# Conditionals in templates with data fetched with getJSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I'm trying to figure out how to do something incredibly simple: Use conditionals in templates with data fetched with getJSON. I need to show info based on the `type` key on the JSON hash. As an example, I've included a HBS file of what'd I'd like to do. What is the Ember Way™ to accomplish this?

**Company route:**

```
// routes/company.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('company', params.company_slug);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);

        Ember.$.getJSON('/companies/%@/events.json'.fmt(model.get('slug'))).then(data => {
            controller.set('events', data);
        });
    }
});
```

**Company show template with example of what I'd like to do:**

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>lol</li>
    {{#each events as |event|}}
        <li class="{{event.type}}">
            {{event.title}}

            {{!-- This code will obviously not work: --}}
            {{#if event.type == 'company_event'}}
               show company event stuff
            {{/if}}
            {{#if event.type == 'user_event'}}
               show user event stuff
            {{/if}}

        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Example of JSON data:**

```
[
    {
        title: "test test test",
        type: "company_event",
        date: "2015-10-14T00:00:00.000+02:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: HTMLBars can only check for booleans using the `if` helper. Write a quick template helper than can check for equality - take a look here: http://emberigniter.com/how-to-equals-conditional-comparison-handlebars/

Comment: The Ember Way is not to use getJSON. Also, the Ember Way is to put asynchronous calls like yours into an `afterModel` hook.The Ember way is to represent things which are models, like `event` as a model. Then I can easily define computed properties such as `isCompanyEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @torazaburo. The data doesn't get used anywhere else in the app, and on the API side it's a collection that gets put together from various data sources, so I thought getJSON would be the best/easiest way to handle it. I'll move it to afterModel for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two suggestions I can think of:

## 1. http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-truth-helpers

```
{{#if (eq event.type 'company_event')}}
  show company event stuff
{{/if}}
```

## 2.a. `{{component}}`

You would have a `company_event` and a `user_event` component (you would need to dasherize the names to comply with the naming rules), and do something like:

```
{{component event.type event}}
```

## 2.b. Wrap it in a component

Another possibility with components is to wrap the whole thing in a component and use computed properties:

```
{{#each events as |event|}}
  {{li-event event=event}}
{{/each}}

// components/li-event.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  classNameBindings: ['event.type'],

  isCompanyEvent: Ember.computed.equal('event.type', 'company_event'),
  isUserEvent: Ember.computed.equal('event.type', 'user_event')
});

// templates/components/li-event.js
{{event.title}}

{{#if isCompanyEvent}}
  show company event stuff
{{/if}}
{{#if isUserEvent}}
  show user event stuff
{{/if}}
```

Which option to choose is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: With regard to `{{component}}`, I'm sure it is a useful thing, even though there was a bit too much hoopla, in my opinion, over its supposed ground-breaking nature. In this case, however, its applicability is severely limited by the fact that if the `event.type` could have a value of `A934CD`, I would have to name my component that. So I end up with some file called `components/A934CD/template.hbs` that no one can find, or refer to, or figure out where it's used from. I'd definitely resist the temptation to use this as what essentially boils down to a poor-man's `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Define `event` as an Ember object so you can define computed properties on it:

```
var eventObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  isCompanyEvent: Ember.computed.equal('type', 'company_event')
});
```

When reading in events, build Ember objects:

```
Ember.$.getJSON('/companies/%@/events.json'.fmt(model.get('slug'))) . 
  then(data => controller.set('events', data.map(event =>
    eventObject.create(event)));
```

Then

```
{{#if event.isCompanyEvent}}
     show company event stuff
```

The developers of Mustache and Handlebars had a clear philosophical perspective that business logic--which they defined broadly--did not belong in templates. Their notion was "you prepare the data, I pump it out". Their objective was first to keep templates simple and readable, but more importantly to keep business rules in one place--most commonly in the equivalent of the controller. For instance, the fact that the `type` property of the `event` object has a possible value of `"company_event"` which has some particular semantics is, in this view, a variety of business logic, and thus **does not belong** in the template, whose job is crank out some HTML. To put it a different way, these developers wanted to avoid a situation where every single change to an interface required changing *n* different things in *n* different places. Certainly, no developer wants to go spelunking through templates to find places where various manifest constants are used to mean magic things. The problem is all the more relevant since whereas with JS code we can easily add logic, in the model, controller, or object, to detect and report on invalid values for fields such as `type`, it is harder, and in practice not common, for programmers to add such error-detection logic to templates; and if they do, it's hard to direct the error output anywhere meaningful. To put it a different way, templates have no equivalent of `assert`.

Which is all a very long-winded way of saying, things like `ember-truth-helpers` are a horrible idea. Two steps forward, one step back. More than a decade after people started separating logic and content using templates, logic is surreptitiously creeping back into content with the connivance of things like the new style of Ember helpers which permit things like `{{#if (eq`.

Comment: 1. Handlebars.js does not follow Mustache's philosophy; 2. There's logic and there's logic, a modicum of presentation logic is fine, algorithmical logic not so much; 3. `ember-truth-helpers` is a collection of very handy helpers, and the point of being able to extend Handlebars with custom helpers.

I agree that people will probably overuse these styles of helpers, but that's true of any tech.

Comment: @locks Thanks for your perspective.

Comment: FYI, just read the Ember 2.1 release notes and found the following: "Using his ember-truth-helpers addon in 1.13 codebases is highly recommended."

Comment: The idea that in 2015 we are talking about a plug-in to compare two variables leaves me speechless.